# Smoothing Page Offset Values During On Scroll Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, parallax

I'm working on a parallax effect for a project and while I have all the animation working great the scroll-driven effect often appears to stutter depending on the input device.

I've ended up using Request Animation Frame (RAF) to check the page offset every animation loop instead of using the basic `.scroll() event for performance reasons. However using either, if I log out the offset/scroll position values the events receive they are often very far apart for a scroll wheel/ball versus a track pad. Because the animation is scroll/offset driven this causes stuttering.

For instance a track pad triggers many events with only a few pixels difference between each event's offset value while a scroll wheel/ball triggers fewer events with 5-15 pixels difference (depending on the scroll speed) leading to a less smooth animation.

You can fool around with this yourself on [this guys fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/jkr1a34u/) that goes like this:

```
$(window).scroll(example);

function example() {
    var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log("Scroll from Top: " + tempScrollTop.toString());
};
```

Anyone know a good library or method for smoothing out these scroll events and their offsets? I know it's possible because I've seen parallax sites where the animations are nice and smooth regardless of input but I can't figure out how it's managed. Thanks.

Comment: If you're doing something like a transform:translate, you can try giving the element a transition in CSS of about 0.25s-0.5s or so. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Yep tried various transition speeds. They all make performance plummet and cause a strange lag between scrolling and the animation.